# Wrong enumerated fields when posting a form containing a reflexive field

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I want to submit a form containing a `reflexive` column :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/ajaxElaborationActivite", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public ModelAndView ajaxElaborationActivite(HttpServletRequest request, HttpSession session) {

    ModelAndView modelView = new ModelAndView("elaboration/elaborationActivite");

    Integer pta_pta_code = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("pta_pta_code"));

    modelView.addObject("action", request.getContextPath().concat("/elaboration/insertActivite"));

    modelView.addObject("responsables", structureDao.list());

    Pta activite = new Pta();
    activite.setParent(ptaDao.get(pta_pta_code));
    activite.setOwner(Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(session.getAttribute("user_code"))));

    modelView.addObject("activite_formulaire", activite);

    return modelView;

}
```

the entity :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "pta")
public class Pta {

    @Id()
    @SequenceGenerator(name="s_pta", sequenceName="s_pta", allocationSize=1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="s_pta")
    @Column(name="pta_code")    
    private Integer code;

    @Column(name="pta_intitule")
    @Lob
    private String lib;

    @Column(name="pta_desc")
    @Lob
    private String descr;

    @Column(name="owner")
    private Integer owner;

    @Column(name="creation")
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
    private Date creation;

    @Column(name="modification")
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
    private Date modification;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "class_pta_code")
    private ClassePta classePta;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "pta_pta_code")
    private Pta parent;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "struct_code")
    private Structure structure;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "exer_code")
    private Exer exercice;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "cdmt_code")
    private Cdmt cdmt;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "pta_pnd" , joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "pta_code")} , inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "pnd_code")} )
    private Set<Pnd> pnds = new HashSet<Pnd>();

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "pta_programme" , joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "pta_code")} , inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "prog_code")} )
    private Set<Pmo> pmos = new HashSet<Pmo>();

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "pta_effet_pmo" , joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "pta_code")} , inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "obj_code")} )
    private Set<Objectif> effets_pmo = new HashSet<Objectif>();

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "pta_produit_pmo" , joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "pta_code")} , inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "obj_code")} )
    private Set<Objectif> produits_pmo = new HashSet<Objectif>();

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "pta_objectif_ddp" , joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "pta_code")} , inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "obj_code")} )
    private Set<Objectif> ddps = new HashSet<Objectif>();

    public Pta() {
        super();
    }

    public Pta(Integer code) {
        super();
    }

    // getters and setters

}
```

the form :

```
<form:form cssClass="form-horizontal" servletRelativeAction="${action}" method="post" commandName="activite_formulaire">

    <form:hidden path="code"/>

    <form:hidden path="parent"/>

    <form:hidden path="owner"/>

    <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
      <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Code</label>
      <div class="col-sm-9">
        <form:input path="lib" cssClass="validate[required] col-sm-4" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
      <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Libell&eacute;</label>
      <div class="col-sm-9">
        <form:textarea path="descr" cssClass="validate[required] col-sm-9" style="padding-left: 1px;" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
      <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Responsable</label>
      <div class="col-sm-9">
        <form:select path="structure" cssClass="col-sm-4">
           <form:option value="" label=" -- S&eacute;lectionner -- "/>
           <form:options items="${responsables}" itemValue="code" itemLabel="lib" />
        </form:select>
      </div>
    </div>

</form:form>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#activite_formulaire").validationEngine();

});

</script>
```

Here is the method treating the post :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/insertActivite", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView insertActivite(@ModelAttribute("activite_formulaire") Pta pta, @RequestParam String structure, @RequestParam String parent, 
                                        HttpServletRequest request, HttpSession session) {

        if (session.getAttribute("user_code") != null) { // test session expirée , ou utilisateur non connecté

            Integer pta_code = ptaDao.insert(pta, exerDao.getExerciceEncours().getExerCode(), structure, "", 2, Integer.parseInt(parent));

            // trace

            Menu menuEncours = menuDao.getMenuTrace(request.getServletPath());

            menuEncours.setEnv(env);

            String trace_txt = env.getProperty("pta.trace.ajout.activite");
            trace_txt = trace_txt.replace("%s", pta.getLib());

            menuDao.insertTrace(String.valueOf(session.getAttribute("user_code")), menuEncours.getId(), trace_txt);

            // fin trace

            ModelAndView modelView = new ModelAndView("redirect:/elaboration/");

            return modelView;

        } else {

            ModelAndView modelView = new ModelAndView("redirect:/");

            modelView.addObject("es", "1");

            return modelView;

        }

    }
```

At runtime I get : `The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect`

So what is wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

I found it : the solution is to **not** make the setting of the parent in the controller but just passing the data to the JSP :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/ajaxElaborationActivite", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public ModelAndView ajaxElaborationActivite(HttpServletRequest request, HttpSession session) {

    ModelAndView modelView = new ModelAndView("elaboration/elaborationActivite");

    Integer pta_pta_code = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("pta_pta_code"));

    modelView.addObject("action", request.getContextPath().concat("/elaboration/insertActivite"));

    modelView.addObject("responsables", structureDao.list());

    Pta activite = new Pta();
    activite.setOwner(Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(session.getAttribute("user_code"))));

    modelView.addObject("parent", pta_pta_code); // here it is

    modelView.addObject("activite_formulaire", activite);

    return modelView;

}
```

So in the JSP :

```
<form:form cssClass="form-horizontal" servletRelativeAction="${action}" method="post" commandName="activite_formulaire">

    <form:hidden path="code"/>

    <input type="hidden" name="ascendant" value="${parent}"/> // here it is , it is mandatory to set the input name to be different to the entity's attribute name

    <form:hidden path="owner"/>

    <fieldset id="resume"><legend>R&eacute;sum&eacute; du PTA</legend>
        <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
          <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Intitul&eacute;</label>
          <div class="col-sm-9">
            <span class="col-sm-12">${fieldset.lib}</span>
          </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>

    <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
      <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Code</label>
      <div class="col-sm-9">
        <form:input path="lib" cssClass="validate[required] col-sm-4" style="padding-left: 1px;" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
      <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Libell&eacute;</label>
      <div class="col-sm-9">
        <form:textarea path="descr" cssClass="validate[required] col-sm-9" style="padding-left: 1px;" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
      <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Responsable</label>
      <div class="col-sm-9">
        <form:select path="structure" cssClass="col-sm-4">
           <form:option value=""/>
           <form:options items="${responsables}" itemValue="code" itemLabel="lib" />
        </form:select>
      </div>
    </div>

</form:form>
```

And in the controller's method treating the form submission :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/insertActivite", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView insertActivite(@ModelAttribute("activite_formulaire") Pta activite, @RequestParam int ascendant, @RequestParam String structure,
                                        HttpServletRequest request, HttpSession session) {

            Integer pta_code = ptaDao.insert(activite, exerDao.getExerciceEncours().getExerCode(), structure, "", 2, ascendant);

            // trace

            Menu menuEncours = menuDao.getMenuTrace(request.getServletPath());

            menuEncours.setEnv(env);

            String trace_txt = menuEncours.getTrace();

            trace_txt = trace_txt.replace("%s", activite.getLib());

            menuDao.insertTrace(String.valueOf(session.getAttribute("user_code")), menuEncours.getId(), trace_txt);

            // fin trace

            ModelAndView modelView = new ModelAndView("redirect:/elaboration/");

            return modelView;

    }
```

Comment: the fact as to name the JSP field to be different than the bean attribute is also valid with general foreign key relationship , not just with reflexive relationship.